# Python re.search inside for-loop is giving false positives. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, if-statement

I am creating a code that automatically updates my website, and when working on a code to identify tags and properly label pages on my database, I encountered a bug that I have no clue of how to fix.
I made a for loop to iterate the .php's lines, then used a if statement to find the tags. But somehow my if statement is responding twice, judging from its output.

First I checked if my regex was giving false positives. Used text editing softwares to manually search using the same regex from the code, but it only found one line.
Then I went to check how re.compile and re.search works, but there was nothing I was doing wrong there.

Here is the portion of the code.

```
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        [Personal information redacted]
        )
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        local = input('Select directory.')
        for paths, dirs, files in os.walk(local):
            for f in files:
                print(f)
                if(splitext(f)[1] == ".php"):
                    print("found .php")
                    opened = open(local + f, 'r')
                    lines = opened.readlines()
                    date = splitext(f)[0]
                    flagD = re.compile(r'<!--desc.')
                    flagS = re.compile(r'<!--subject.')
                    flagE = re.compile(r'-->')
                    desc = None
                    subject = None
                    for l in lines:
                        if(flagD.search(l) != None):
                            print("found desc")
                            desc = re.sub(flagD, "",l)
                            descF = re.sub(flagE,"",desc)
                        if(flagS.search(l) != None):
                            print("found subj")
                            subject = re.sub(flagS, "",l)
                            subjectF = re.sub(flagE,"",subject)
                    if(desc == None or subject == None):
                        continue
                    sql = "INSERT INTO arquivos (quando, descricao, assunto, file) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
                    val = (date, descF, subjectF, f)
                    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
                    mydb.commit()
```

and this is the output:

```
2018-11-15.php
found .php
2018-11-16.php
found .php
2018-11-26.php
found .php
2019-01-13.php
found .php
2019-01-15.php
found .php
2019-01-16.php
found .php
2019-01-17.php
found .php
2019-01-22.php
found .php
found desc
found subj
2019-01-24.php
found .php
found desc
found desc
found subj
found subj
BdUpdate.php
found .php
BdUpdate1.php
found .php
Comentarios.php
found .php
FINAL.php
found .php
Foot.inc
Formulario.php
found .php
FormularioCompleto.php
found .php
Head.inc
index.php
found .php
index1.php
found .php
Java.php
found .php
Layout Base - Copy.php
found .php
Layout Base.php
found .php
Php_Test.ste
Phyton.php
found .php
SalvandoDB.php
found .php
sidenav.inc
Side_Menu.php
found .php
Thema.php
found .php
Translations.php
found .php
Web.php
found .php
2019-01-13.php
found .php
```

As you can see, somehow the `print("found desc")` and `print("found subj")`
is being called twice within one `print("found .php")`. Meaning it is giving a false positive somewhere in my code, but it is simply impossible, as I tested this regex in other softwares. This is totally unintended, and leaves the rest of the code as a entry on my database.
Edit: Sorry for the delay. here is the .php that is being scanned at the unexpected return part.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--desc Today I attempted to learn django, but a lot went wrong and I couldn't do it.-->
<!--subject:Java-->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Training Diary</title>
<?php
// Establecer la zona horaria predeterminada a usar. Disponible desde PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
$pasta=date("F");
echo '<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "';
echo "$pasta";
echo '/estilo.css"/>';
?>
<link href="January/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="Around Table">
<tr>
<td width="100%" height="100%" valign="top">
<!--HEADER -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="Header">
<tr>
<td id="claro"><img src="img/spc.png" width="140" height="40" alt="space_Header">
</td>
<td width="100%" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" id="claro">
<div id="banner"></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="escuro"><img src="img/spc.png" width="140" height="20" alt="space_Header">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>

</tr>   
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="Meio">
<tr>
<td height="100%" valign="top" id="escuro">
<base target="_top">
<div align="center" id="Side">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<!--MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU-->
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdcomentarios");
$executar=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while( $exibir = mysqli_fetch_array($executar)){
    echo '<td align="center" bordercolor="#2A628F" id="claro">';
    echo '<a href="';
    echo $exibir['assunto'];
    echo '.php" id="Side">';
    echo $exibir['assunto'];
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</td></tr><tr>';
}
mysqli_close($con)
?>
<!--FIM MENU FIM MENU FIM MENU FIM MENU FIM-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<img src="img/spc.png" width="140" height="1" alt="space_Meio">
</td>
<td width="100%" height="100%">
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
<h2> Creative ways to iterate 

</h2><br><p>Today I fixed 2 things.

<br>The first one, is that the methods of the classes that implements Pieces, was calling the Pieces' method,

<br>instead of their own. I took the method declaration, removed it and replaced it with an abstract method so the entire

<br>code does not glitch due to the absence of Move().

<br>Then, I noticed that the evaluation on notBlocked() on diagonal moves was wrong.

<br>Before, I was using nested for loops to iterate through the blocks it will move through.

<br>But as you may have noticed, that means that it will evaluate a square area instead of a diagonal line.

<br>So, I made a single for loop inside nested if statements that determine which angle it is moving on,

<br>Example: if(positionX > destinationX){if(positionY > destinationY)for(int i....) (this means it is moving down-left because both values are going down.)

<br>then made it return the piece on each square, and I expressed it with subtracting or adding the current loop number to the original position.

<br>Meaning, if you are on the second loop, and you want to see if there is a piece at 2 squares below AND left, it is x minus loop No. and y minus loop No.

<br>And by making different ways of iterating, I succeeded in correctly evaluating the bishop (and the queen's) movement.

<br>Now there is only 3 more unexpected returns to fix.

<br>More coming soon. <br><br><br>

    <h2>Visitors Comments, Thanks!</h2>
    <table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" id"postcomments">
Name:(Show)<br>
<input type="CHAR" name="nome">
<br><br>E-Mail:(Hide)<br>
<input type="text" name= "email">
<br><br>Message:(Show)<br>
<textarea name="comentario"></textarea>
<br><br>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="pagina" VALUE="<!--DATE-->">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
<input type="reset" value="Limpar">
</form>
<hr>
</td></tr></table>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$nome = "";
$email = "";
$comentario = "";
$pagina ="";
//keep the variables
if(isset($_POST["nome"]))
     $nome = $_POST["nome"];
if(isset($_POST["email"]))
     $email = $_POST["email"];
if(isset($_POST["comentario"]))
     $comentario = $_POST["comentario"];
if(isset($_POST["pagina"]))
     $pagina = $_POST["pagina"];

//current date
$date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
$data = date("Y/m/d");
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdcomentarios");

//EU COLOQUEI
if(isset($_POST["nome"],$_POST["pagina"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["comentario"], $_POST["data"]));

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$sql_insert="INSERT INTO tbcomentarios (data, nome, email, comentario, pagina) 
VALUES('$data', '$nome', '$email', '$comentario', '$pagina')";

//check the insert into DB
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql_insert)) {
echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">
alert("Sua mensagem foi gravada com sucesso. Obrigado");
location.href="<!--DATE-->.php";
</script>';
}
else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}



$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbcomentarios WHERE pagina like '%<!--DATE-->%' ORDER BY id desc";
$executar=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while( $exibir = mysqli_fetch_array($executar)){
    echo $exibir['data'];
    echo "<br><b>Name:</b>";
    echo $exibir['nome'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<b>E-mail:</b>*********";
    echo "<br><b>Comment:</b><br>";
    echo $exibir['comentario'];
    echo "<br><hr>";
}
}
?>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbcomentarios WHERE pagina like '%<!--DATE-->%' ORDER BY id desc";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdcomentarios");
$executar=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while( $exibir = mysqli_fetch_array($executar)){
    echo '<table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>';
    echo $exibir['data'];
    echo "<br><b>Name:</b>";
    echo $exibir['nome'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<b>E-mail:</b>*********";
    echo "<br><b>Comment:</b><br>";
    echo $exibir['comentario'];
    echo "<br><hr>";
    echo '</td></tr></table>';
}
?></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--Foot -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="Foot">
<tr>
<td id="escuro""><img src="img/spc.png" width="140" height="30" alt="space_Foot">
</td>
<td width="100%" valign="bottom" id="escuro">
<div id="Foot">
<table align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" summary="Foot Menu">
<tr>
<!--FOOT MENU FOOT MENU FOOT MENU FOOT MENU-->
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdcomentarios");
$executar=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while( $exibir = mysqli_fetch_array($executar)){
    echo '<td align="center" valign="bottom"><a href="';
    echo $exibir['assunto'];
    echo '.php">';
    echo $exibir['assunto'];
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</td>';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, when I said I checked with "other softwares", I meant that I went to notepad++, then made a regex search with the exact same regex, and it was working as intended.
I hope this information will help identify the problem.
Thanks in advance.

PS. Most of my questions is getting closed or locked and no one explains why. I have edited past questions to match the guidelines but the question is buried soon after. Please stop.

Comment: If your other questions are like this, you've asserted it being a false positive, without any proof and somehow your `other softwares` tests it right? A file could have lines that match both regexs. Show the minimal software file that matches, otherwise nothing can be independently validated and you'll have another closed/locked question.

Comment: "found desc"/"found subj" can be printed any number of times for each "found .php"; they're inside a `for` loop, after all.  There is apparently more than one line in the problem file that contains your strings.  Perhaps you want to `break` out of that innermost loop after finding a match?

Comment: I cannot break that loop because it has to find 2 matches, and if I break either of them there will be a chance it will only match one, thus triggering the `if(desc == None or subject == None): Continue`.

Comment: What is your expected output for that sample? As far as I can see it will produce the correct output. Perhaps some of your files contain multiple HTML blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to parse each file a line at a time, it would also be possible to extract the two
values using a single multiline regex. For example the following shows how it could be done for a single
test file:

```
from os.path import splitext
import re

f = 'test.php'
re_desc_subject = re.compile(r'<!--desc.([^\r\n]*?)-->.*?<!--subject.([^\r\n]*?)-->', re.M + re.S + re.I)

with open(f) as f_input:
    data = f_input.read()

desc_subject = re_desc_subject.search(data)

if desc_subject:
    desc, subject = desc_subject.groups()
    print(desc, subject)
```

So for your code, this would work as follows:

```
re_desc_subject = re.compile(r'<!--desc.([^\r\n]*?)-->.*?<!--subject.([^\r\n]*?)-->', re.M + re.S + re.I)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
[Personal information redacted]
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

local = input('Select directory.')

for paths, dirs, files in os.walk(local):
    for f in files:
        print(f)

        if splitext(f)[1] == ".php":
            print("found .php")

            with open(os.path.join(local, f)) as f_input:
                data = f_input.read()

            desc_subject = re_desc_subject.search(data)

            if desc_subject:
                desc, subject = desc_subject.groups()
                print("Found desc and subject")

                sql = "INSERT INTO arquivos (quando, descricao, assunto, file) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
                val = (date, desc, subject, f)
                mycursor.execute(sql, val)
                mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Maybe it was the actual text that had problems, just like you commented.